# Mouse enter and mouse leave events in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 4 image buttons. I wrote some JavaScript code for changing the color of image on mouseenter. Also on mouseleave, it will back to the original state as shown below.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">             
    function mouseOverImage(Id) {                       
       document.getElementById(Id).src = "Images/Yellow.png";
    }

    function mouseOutImage(Id) {    
       document.getElementById(Id).src = "Images/TestImage.png";                 
    }
</script>
```

If I click on button1, I have to change the color to yellow and mouse leave event could not be fired on this situvation.

If I click on `button2`, `button1` should back to original state.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please make sure your page is not post back if it dose then you need to track the button by which your page is post back to set css or image source.

Answer (score 2):

Its easier if you use jQuery, Here's some sample code

```
$('#button1').on('click', function () {
    //button 1 click event goes here
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(Images/Yellow.png)");
});

$('#button1').hover(
    function () {
        //button 1 hover event
    },
    function () {
       //button 1 hover out event 
    });

$('#button2').on('click', function () {
    //button 2 click event goes here
    $('#button1').css("background-image", "url(Images/Original.png)");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try,

```
 $(document).on(
    {
        mouseenter: function () {

        },
        mouseleave: function () {

        }
    }, '.chat-button');
```

chat-button is -> button2 and button1 client id

jquery 1.9.x